# System Error 67 When Mounting a SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-2007, windows-server-2003

I have a library created and I am trying to mount that library on one of our servers running Windows Server 2003.  I am able to mount the site on my own machine which is running XP, but when I try to mount it on the server it throws System Error 67.  I am using `net use z: \\sharepointsite` to mount it on both machines.  Obviously there is a difference between the server OS and the PC OS that is preventing me from mounting it.  Does anyone know of a way to fix this or a work-around?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after digging around a little bit I found out that the WebClient service was turned off on the Windows Server machine.  After turning that on the server was able to mount the sharepoint site using `net use http://sharepointsite/folder`.